# Iterate through the table in protractor

Tags: protractor

Hi all below is my html table. I am trying compare all the element values of the below table using protractor.

```
<table>
    <thead class="ui-table-thead">
            <tr _ngcontent-c1="" class="ng-tns-c1-0 ng-star-inserted">
                <th _ngcontent-c1="" class="ng-tns-c1-0" rowspan="2" style="text-align: center">User</th>
                <th _ngcontent-c1="" class="ng-tns-c1-0" colspan="5" style="text-align: center">Support</th>
            </tr>
            <tr _ngcontent-c1="" class="ng-tns-c1-0 ng-star-inserted">
                <th _ngcontent-c1="" class="ng-tns-c1-0" style="text-align: center">User1</th>
                <th _ngcontent-c1="" class="ng-tns-c1-0" style="text-align: center">User2</th>
                <th _ngcontent-c1="" class="ng-tns-c1-0" style="text-align: center">User3</th>
                <th _ngcontent-c1="" class="ng-tns-c1-0" style="text-align: center">User4</th>
                <th _ngcontent-c1="" class="ng-tns-c1-0" style="text-align: center">User4</th>
                </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="ui-table-tbody">
            <tr _ngcontent-c1="" class="ng-tns-c1-0 ng-star-inserted">
                <td _ngcontent-c1="" class="ng-tns-c1-0">value1</td>
                <td _ngcontent-c1="" class="ng-tns-c1-0">value2</td>
                <td _ngcontent-c1="" class="ng-tns-c1-0">value3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr _ngcontent-c1="" class="ng-tns-c1-0 ng-star-inserted">
                <td _ngcontent-c1="" class="ng-tns-c1-0">value11</td>
                <td _ngcontent-c1="" class="ng-tns-c1-0">value12</td>
                <td _ngcontent-c1="" class="ng-tns-c1-0">value13</td>
            </tr>
            <tr _ngcontent-c1="" class="ng-tns-c1-0 ng-star-inserted">
                <td _ngcontent-c1="" class="ng-tns-c1-0">value21</td>
                <td _ngcontent-c1="" class="ng-tns-c1-0">value22</td>
                <td _ngcontent-c1="" class="ng-tns-c1-0">value23</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

unable to get the right solution.Any help will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Only compare the value in tbody or includes values in table header.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "compare values"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    function AddBetternameforfuntionhere(){
    var headerRows = element.all(by.css(".ui-table-thead")).first().all(by.tagName('tr'));
    var headerIndex = headerRows.all(by.tagName('th'));
    var counter = 0;

    headerIndex.getText().then(function(conforms){
        conforms.forEach(function(value){
           //perform the validation here
        })
    })
    }
```

The forEach will iterate till the end of the array got in .getText()

For the body the code is similar, if you want to validate the specific column for example you can use this to get the values:

```
        var expectedCells = element.all(by.css('#'+/*TableId*/+' tr td:nth-of-type('+columnNumber+')'));
    expectedCells.each((eachCell) => {
        eachCell.getText().then((cellText) => {
            expect(cellText).toBe(arrayOfvalues);
        });
    });
```

Comment: first() means the first tr tag right.? and is it possible to get count the number of headers?

Comment: first is used to tell protractor that if there are more items with the same class (or any other selector you use) you want to get the first one of them, to get the second and son on use .get(2) for example instead of .first()